# Change CytoPanel Height

Tags: java, swing

I've got a JPanel whose contents are too big vertically to be displayed in the south CytoPanel. Is there a way I can set the preferred size of the CytoPanel? I'm using the CytoPanelImp class in which to put my JPanel. Calling `southPanel.setSize(new Dimension (0, 1000));` or `southPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (0, 1000));` has no effect on its size.

Comment: If a component is too big to be shown completely, generally you add it to a JScrollPane first before adding the scroll pane to another component.

Comment: What is a CytoPanel? Not standard Java nor Swing, is it?

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger http://cytoscape.wodaklab.org/wiki/CytoPanel_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Try it with southPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,1000)).

If you post the code of your layout it can be easier to get this working.